# Mirrored mesh lines disappear when moving from edit to object mode and back to edit mode

Tags: mesh

Mirrored mesh lines disappear when moving from edit to object mode and back to edit mode. The right side (source for the mirrored left side) remains normal, but the mirrored left side shows only the outline of the outer edges of the overall shape of the object.  I checked in object properites and made sure maximum draw type wasn't set to 'bounds.' Help?

This is a simple mirrored mesh I created as an example.
[image]

I switch to object mode and then right back to edit mode.  This is what remains.
[image]

Comment: Blender isn't deleting anything. It is just hiding the edges that separate coplanar faces to make the mesh easier to view. If you still want to see them, check "Draw All Edges" above the "Maximum Draw Type" setting.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to enable the options highlighted in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal effect of the mirror modifier, if you want to to have access to the other side, then you will need to apply the mirror modifier first in object mode as shown:

[image]

And then you will have access to all the vertices, edges and faces as shown below:

[image]